# How to remove iPhoto auto open when device connects with USB?

Tags: macos, iphoto

When I connect any device using USB cable (mobile,tablet) on my Mac PC , iPhoto starts up and 
hangs my system for sometime ...

Comment: This question is totally unrelated to programming, and you didn't even bother to google first: http://apple-iphoto.wonderhowto.com/how-to/disable-iphotos-auto-open-when-you-connect-camera-363873/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about.
Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Open the iPhoto application go to the preference -- > General --
>   Connecting Camera Opens (combo box) change option iPhoto to No
>   Application . Reconnect USB cable now the problem would be solved.